# Flutter: How to push a navigation route without the back button?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I understand that `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` allows you to replace the current screen on the back stack, but how do you handle cases where the current screen already has its own back button?

I've noticed if I use the `.pushReplacementNamed` function in this case, it retains the back button from the previous screen, but I would like to have this flow:

Screen A `.pushNamed` -> Screen B (able to navigate back to A) `.pushReplacementNamed` -> Screen C (should not be able to navigate back to either B or A)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using an `AppBar` widget on the targetted screen, make sure you add this line inside your `AppBar` widget, which will prevent the app from automatically adding a back button by default on the `AppBar` :

```
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
```

But, either you use `AppBar` or not and you don't wanna go to the previous screen by clicking on the back button(physical button or Cupertino slide gesture), you have to use `WillPopScope` as the root widget on the target screen. Also, your `onWillPop` method should look like this:

```
onWillPop: () async => false,
```

by returning false, you are restricting your screen from leaving the screen and you can't exit the app now by clicking the back button. Because you are returning `false` as the decision if you want to go back or not. You can use `exit(0)` on this point inside the `onWillPop` method if you wish to close the app's new screen.

Answer (score 1):

you should wrap root Widget with WillPopScope to be able handle back button

example below

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("WillPopScope example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Back'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Overriding back buttons might help you.

Please search for **leading argument for appBar** and **WillPopScope**